# What to type in console to trigger end of stream?

Tags: c++

Following code is from the book: The C++ Standard Library Second Edition.

how to run it on Mac Yosemite?

in the console, I typed a, enter, b, enter...no ends.... how to input end-of-stream?

```
/* The following code example is taken from the book
 * "The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference, 2nd Edition"
 * by Nicolai M. Josuttis, Addison-Wesley, 2012
 *
 * (C) Copyright Nicolai M. Josuttis 2012.
 * Permission to copy, use, modify, sell and distribute this software
 * is granted provided this copyright notice appears in all copies.
 * This software is provided "as is" without express or implied
 * warranty, and with no claim as to its suitability for any purpose.
 */
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> coll;

    // read all words from the standard input
    // - source: all strings until end-of-file (or error)
    // - destination: coll (inserting)
    copy (istream_iterator<string>(cin),    // start of source
          istream_iterator<string>(),       // end of source
          back_inserter(coll));             // destination

    // sort elements
    sort (coll.begin(), coll.end());

    // print all elements without duplicates
    // - source: coll
    // - destination: standard output (with newline between elements)
    unique_copy (coll.cbegin(), coll.cend(),           // source
                 ostream_iterator<string>(cout,"\n")); // destination
}
```

Comment: "end of file terminal <your OS>" should net search results.

Comment: It depends on what OS you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl-D on Mac OS and other UNIX derivatives.

Comment: No idea how to do it on the cpp.sh web interface. Wouldn't be surprised if you can't.